# Blockchain save destination folder

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am going to activate a Bitcoin Core full node on my PC. Selecting a custom folder in which to save the blockchain, however, I get the error message:
"A fatal error occured. Bitcoin can no longer continue safely and will quit.".
The only button I can press is "OK", after which the Bitcoin Core application crashes / closes and restarting it, the same error appears again each time. Is it a bug or is it something wanted by the developers not to be able to change the save destination folder of the blockchain?
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04, my Bitcoin Core version is 0.19.0.1 (Snap).

Thank you.

Comment: Would help to share how exactly you are passing the custom folder details.

Comment: By starting Bitcoin Core for the first time, when it asks where I want to save the blockchain, I can check the box that corresponds to the default folder, or click below to choose it manually. I then type in the path I have chosen, which in my case is a folder created ad hoc in Home.
Giving the ok, here is the error and the only action I can do is press OK. After that Bitcoin Core closes on its own and when I try to restart it, the only thing that appears on the screen is the error message mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure the user that runs the app has permissions to write there? Can you create the folder before starting the app and then choose it?

Comment: I have PC administrator permissions, also I personally created the folder in question in Home and its subfolders successfully before installing Bitcoin Core.

Comment: Can you include the contents of the debug.log file? It should be found in that folder. If not, check whether it is in the original datadir.